# How did the Tesla roadster probe push away from earth's orbit?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy

I know every rocket/probe has to revolve around the Earth and then push out of the Earth's orbit to reach mars. So what exactly is kicking the rocket to push out of that orbit?

Comment: The engine that put it into orbit?

Comment: Why do you think there is an *orbit*, then a *jump*? There aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really have to, indeed I think most modern Mars probes are launched directly into the orbit that will take them to Mars, since you use slightly less fuel that way.

Musk's car actually did go into orbit though, in order to demonstrate some features of the rocket that the US Department of Defence are interested in. The car was (and is, I think) still attached to the upper stage of the rocket, and that simply fired again after a few hours in orbit to finally break free from the Earth and go into an orbit around the sun.

Comment: Re *I think most modern Mars probes are launched directly into the orbit that will take them to Mars, since you use slightly less fuel that way.*: That's not the case. Most are launched into a LEO parking orbit from which the vehicle is later injected to a Mars transfer orbit. For example, the Mars Science Laboratory was launched into a 165×324 km parking orbit, with TMI occurring about 20 minutes after insertion into that parking orbit.

Comment: Insertion into a parking orbit has two advantages. One is that it enables a non-instantaneous launch window, obviously an advantage over the instantaneous launch window required for Insertion directly into the Mars transfer orbit. Another is that it enables a better assessment of uncertainties due to launch, which potentially reduces total fuel consumption.

Comment: Go into an orbit around the **sun**? How ?

Comment: @Gandalf107 By leaving Earth orbit on escape trajectory.